# Excel Macro -Cells() why fail?

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to macro . Iam using this code for concatenating two column values into one column. This code today failed , for 10 first rows of the sheet , and it worked for the rest of the rows.Why happened like this , i havent changed anything at all !
Thanks.

```
Sub FixCrossSell()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lr As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets("CrossSell").Activate

    Cells(2, 1).Value = "=B2&E2"

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("A3:A" & lr).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.Calculate

    Range("A2:A" & lr).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: What was the input of the first 10 rows of the sheet?

Comment: You are calculating `lr` but then never using it. Your code as is doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JohnColeman - `lr` was used in the other "editions" of the question.

Comment: Column A has to concat values from column B and E .In column B i have a number 2, and in column E i have a name 'TEST', so column A should be '2TEST' , but in fact it was very different , example : '11NOTHING' . Im really surprised with this , because this failed only for 78 first rows of the sheet , and for the rest is ok.

Comment: The code only works for one cell A2, what other rows are you referring to?

Comment: How did the code failed, is there any error code etc? And how do you loop through the rows, can you provide that part too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FiXCrossSell()
    Dim lr As Long
    With Worksheets("CrossSell")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A2:A" & lr)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=rc2&rc5"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably just count the cells in column B, then place the Formula in Column A

```
  Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, Sh As Worksheet

    Set Sh = Sheets("CrossSell")
    With Sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw)
        Rng = "=B2&E2"
    End With
End Sub
```

Ah.. I see someone else answered this while I was thinking about it.